Form Submit Event is not being trigged from Button with type Submit inside Form
I'm encountering an issue with a custom LoadingButton component in my React TypeScript project using the Material-UI (MUI) library. The problem arises when I use this LoadingButton within a form that has an onSubmit event handler. The LoadingButton has a type="submit", and when I click on it, the form's onSubmit event function does not get executed. However, if I remove the setLoading(true) call from the handleClick function of the LoadingButton, the form submission works as expected.
Below is the code for the LoadingButton component:
import { Button, ButtonProps, CircularProgress } from "@mui/material";
import React, {
  forwardRef,
  MouseEvent,
  useImperativeHandle,
  useState,
} from "react";

interface LoadingButtonWrapperProps extends ButtonProps {
  // You can add other custom props here if needed
}

interface LoadingButtonWrapperHandle {
  disableLoading: () => void;
}

const LoadingButton = forwardRef<
  LoadingButtonWrapperHandle,
  LoadingButtonWrapperProps
>((props, ref) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  // Expose the setLoading function to the parent component
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    disableLoading,
  }));

  const disableLoading = () => {
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const handleClick = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    if (props.onClick) {
      props.onClick(e);
    }
    setLoading(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {loading ? <CircularProgress size={24} /> : null}
      <Button {...props} disabled={loading} onClick={handleClick}>
        {props.children}
      </Button>
    </>
  );
});

export default LoadingButton;


Issue:-
When the setLoading(true) is called within the handleClick function, the form's onSubmit event does not get triggered. If I remove the setLoading(true) call, the form submission works correctly.
Steps to Reproduce -

Create a form with an onSubmit event handler.
Use the LoadingButton component with type="submit" inside the form.
Click the LoadingButton to submit the form.

Expected Behavior
The form's onSubmit event handler should be executed when the LoadingButton is clicked, even with the setLoading(true) call.
Actual Behavior
The form's onSubmit event handler is not executed when the LoadingButton is clicked if setLoading(true) is called within the handleClick function of LoadingButton.
Thanks,

The essential problem in your code is, that after you press on your button, you are setting your button to disabled. Because the code inside the handleClick function is executed before the submit handler, the submit event wont get executed, because the button is disabled.
A possible solution would be that you set the setLoading state AFTER the submit event is executed.
Or you could do:
<>
  {loading ? <CircularProgress size={24} /> 
     : 
  <Button {...props} onClick={handleClick}>
    {props.children}
  </Button>}
  
</>

Assuming you want to display the loading progress instead of the button.

Thanks Davyd, I tried by removing the code to disable the button onClick but it still doesn't execute the submit event of the form where I'm using LoadingButton component. How can I call the setLoading after the submit is executed in the same component?

I got the issue in above. The button component gets inserted only when the loading is false so when I do setLoading(true) the button gets off from webpage hence the submit event was not executed. However as mentioned by @Davyd Shapovalov it should not be disabled anyhow.
